# Math newbie here. Need help with functions

Tags: functions

I know this is a website for advanced problems, but I am having trouble with a pretty simple one.
I was never any good at functions, and now have an assignment on them.
I need help with all the questions I've attached..

[image: These are the values we're working with]

[And these are the questions we're supposed to answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koWMc.jpg)

From the values we're given, I've concluded that the equation is $-0.5x+14$, but I'm having trouble applying that to the questions.
I'd be ever so grateful for an explanation as to how to do it.

Comment: First, welcome to MSE. Second, you should make your question self-contained. That is, users should not have to click around to see what your question is. Also, make your question singular as opposed to plural. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. I do wish to help you, but there are some quality standards for the questions that have to be met. If you think your question is simple, don't worry. This site has plenty of seemingly noob questions which are well received and thoroughly answered. For starters, please provide some context and try to [use MathJax for typesetting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The _equation_ is $p(x) = -05.x+14$, assuming we're supposed to infer a linear function. But your book (or your instructor) has a peculiar way of naming the variables; I would have called $x$ the _independent_ variable of the function $p$, and $p(x)$ the _dependent_ variable. Economics textbooks seem to be a little hazy sometimes about which variable is dependent or independent (or they'll plot the input of a function vertically and the output horizontally), so maybe that's where this terminology comes from?

Answer (score 1):

You have solved (I'm assuming you did this correctly! If it's not then everything will be wrong):

$$ p(x) = 0.5 x + 14$$

So this means the price is half of the quantity demanded, plus 14 kr. Solving for the quantity now gives:

$$ \mbox{Price} = 0.5 \mbox{ Quantity} + 14$$

$$ 2 \mbox{Price} = \mbox{ Quantity} + 28$$

$$ 2 \mbox{Price} - 28 = \mbox{ Quantity} $$

$$ 2 p - 28 = x$$

Can you solve the first two questions now? I'm not sure quite what they mean by turnover but I think it should just be quantity multiplied by the price.